# Why does this function need to be inside document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just spent an ungodly number of hours trying to figure why a simple function won't activate in the debugger.  Eventually I put it in document.ready and it worked.  However on other pages, similar functions work outside of document ready.  Could anyone think of a reason why this is happening?

the simple function:

```
$('#chk').change(function () {

....
}
```

on the page:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
```

Comment: Do you know in general what document.ready does and why it's used?

Comment: It depends on how much javascript code have to implement on the page.

Comment: Think of it as an initialization of the page. You have html elements that needs to have som functions assosiated to them when the page is ready. And btw, it's not a function you are refering to, it's an event listener. But you can have a function outside of the event listener, like function Test() and then the .change event kan call that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready` fires on `DOMContentLoaded`, which means that whole html source has been processed, and you are sure that you can access your input

if you ommit that and place your script before `<input id="chk">` then it won't work because at the time of script execution it doesn't find your input

Comment: "is unlikely to" -> "won't" - be assertive :)

Comment: ok I understand, but how do I know whether a html element will be loaded before or after the event listener?  eg on another page the exact same function works outside the document.ready.

Comment: @BMills maybe `script` tag there is included after `input` element; another possible cause might be using `async` attribute with your script tag

Comment: right thanks. I suspected I would negative votes for this question, but it was worth it because I understand better now.  I don't know why people would downvote someone just trying to learn.

Answer (score -2):

Is it a very large page? It's possible the javascript starts running before the browser is finished building its DOM. Putting code inside the document ready means the code won't be called until the DOM is 100% complete.

Comment: Page size is nothing to do with it - it's entirely down to the order of where things are located.